# How to open a cash drawer when sale is made in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Keystroke POS software which is in C# asp.net based.  I have an Epson TM-U325D receipt printer hooked to COM1.  I have a cash drawer Model SI-420R. It hooks to the Epson receipt printer through an RJ11 connection.

How do I get this program or printer to open the cash drawer when a sale is made?

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

- The cash drawer can normally be "kicked" as soon as the printer prints (This is configured in the printer driver) In your case, this seems logical, as your drawer is connected to your printer.
- The other option, is to get a "kicker", that connects to your pc, on a comm port. The cash drawer connects to the kicker, and you send a serial string to the kicker to tell it to open the drawer.
- Read the manual, as @Sayse suggested.

Comment: can u define what it means by serial string?